# Ignoring noweb syntax in html export

Tags: emacs, org-babel, noweb

I have an org doc that contains:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org
  ,#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/thing/doc/1' -d'{"body": "foo"}'
  curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/thing/doc/2' -d'{"body": "bar"}'
  <<refresh>>
  ,#+END_SRC
#+END_SRC
```

And I'd like to actually ignore the `<<refresh>>` so it exports correctly as the actual text `<<refresh>>` when I export HTML (this is for an article demonstrating org-babel and noweb). Instead, it's exporting as a blank space, how can I get it to export verbatim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want noweb syntax disabled for exporting, but enabled for tangling you can use :noweb no-export

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org :noweb no-export
  ,#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/thing/doc/1' -d'{"body": "foo"}'
  curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/thing/doc/2' -d'{"body": "bar"}'
  <<refresh>>
  ,#+END_SRC
#+END_SRC
```

See http://orgmode.org/manual/noweb.html#noweb

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of exporting HTML in my Emacs 24.3.1 (Org mode 8.1.1):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/thing/doc/1' -d'{"body": "foo"}'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/thing/doc/2' -d'{"body": "bar"}'
<<refresh>>
#+END_SRC
```

There is no blank space, `<<refresh>>` is exporting verbatim. That is your version of `org-mode`?